# Door handle not opening fully (not retracting door latch)

Tags: doors

I have taken apart the handle to try and fix it. The issue is I cannot physically turn the door handle enough to retract the latch. Can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: What does the part (still in the door) which this fits into look like? If you jam a large screwdriver (or whatever fits) into that part and rotate it about 45 degrees, does the latch retract appropriately?

Comment: Yes it does! It's just that (from what I gather) the door handle has a metal piece that prevents it from turning it enough.

Comment: If all I need to do is buy a new inner door piece (or handle set) I guess I can do that relatively cheaply. Just find it strange.

Comment: Aaand - just so we can get the obvious out of the way - if you turn that knob you're holding in the photo over there isn't a little button/twisty-thingy  which you can push/toggle/turn ... ?

Comment: The door insert? It does retract when the door handle is inserted. Just not fully. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: No - the handle you're holding in the photo.

Comment: Ah, then no. There is no toggle button or anything I can do to the handle (as far as I know)

Comment: Your door hardware may simply not have been aligned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to close this question. Ultimately, I ended up replacing the door handles. Trying to fix the components was just too time consuming for me, personally.

Comment: Thank you for closing the question. You are a noble person.